# Application won't deploy from Laptop

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment

I've been working on my program for about two years on and off. I've always done so on my PC in Visual Studio 2015/17. The program works on all the work PCs without issue.

I recently got a new laptop and have begun programming in Visual Studio Community 17 (Same as PC) - working from the same source as my PC, but whenever I deploy the application it won't run on the work machines.

I copied and pasted the code to the PC version and it deployed perfectly. They're using the same code, same framework, everything.

To get it on my work PC I have to password protect and Zip it. When I do, I can't get the application out of the zip on to the PC - getting an undefined error. When copied to my work laptop directly, same issue. Unable to run.

The program has a couple of dependencies - so I created another one (simple buttons on a grid in a window) on my laptop from scratchb- to rule out these causing the problem - but this experienced the problem exact same problem with the undefined error and app not running.

I'm going to reinstall VS and see if this resolves the problem, but has anyone experienced this before?

Thanks!

Anthony

Comment: It's related to your deployment technique not VS.

Comment: The deployment is the exact swme

Comment: The deployment is the exact aame in both scenarios. Everything is standard and default. Uninstalling didn't work to fix it. I can load the same project from my external harddrive, compile it on my pc and it's fine. Laptop just gives me errors.